# How to reload whole page without refresh in angular 7,8?

Tags: angular, refresh, reload

> I am working with angular 8 and want to refresh my component on same
>   url without refresh whole page. I am trying with router.navigate but
>   its not working for me. I tried with `location.reload` and
>   `window.location.reload` but it takes too much time and it refresh
>   whole page. Below is my code for same :

```
this.snackBar.open('Data Updated Successfully', 'Undo', {
        duration: 5000,
      });
      this.router.navigate(['/get_customer_details/'+this.customer_details_id]);
      console.log(this.customer_details_id);
      this.ngOnInit();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default `RouteReuseStrategy` of Angular is true. You need to cahnge it to false.

Use the following code in your constructor

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false;
  }
```